# SVI as a DHCP client

Tags: switch, vlan, dhcp, mac-address, interface

Can a Cisco switch be configured to have a management interface (or SVI, or VLAN interface) become a DHCP client, therefore obtaining its own IP address on the respective network?

This is out of curiousity, as I have not been able to come across the correct options in the CLI.

It may not be possible due to the same MAC address of the virtual interface being used in various transmissions on the switch, but please let me know!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can configure an SVI as a dhcp client by using the following command within the SVI.

```
ip address dhcp
```

The same command is used on physical interfaces as well.

Comment: Note: not *all* switches support this. ('tho modern ones should)

Comment: I suppose it all depends on the IOS version and switch model.

Answer (score 0):

Default configuration of a VLAN interface is `no ip address`. Thus, by default the switch is not a DHCP client. (it has no address at all.) `ip address dhcp` is the configuration to use DHCP.